# ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensowFlow via `pip install tensorflow`

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Tengo un archivo de Python corriendo desde Laravel:

```
$process = new Process(['python', 'Prediccion.py', $imagen]);
        $process->run();

        if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
            throw new ProcessFailedException($process);
        }
        $process->getOutput();
```

le paso por parametro una imagen. Estas son las librerias que uso en el archivo de Python:

```
import numpy as np
import sys
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img, img_to_array
from keras.models import load_model
```

Cuando corro este programa desde el cmd, todo resulta bien, pero al correrlo desde Laravel me dice que necesito instalar tensorflow y keras, pero no se como hacerlo desde laravel, en general de Laragon, esto es lo que me muestra:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Este error no tiene que ver con Laravel, ahí te indica que instales una versión específica de tensorflow

Comment: pero tengo tensorflow 3 y cuando corro el mismo archivo de python con el shell de windows, todo sale bien :/

Comment: No puedes tener Tensorflow 3, la versión más reciente que existe es la 2.4. Lo que te está ocurriendo es que probablemente tengas varios entornos de Python, tienes que encontrar el que tiene Tensorflow instalado y usar ese. O descubrir cual es el que estás llamando con Laravel e instalar Tensorlfow.

Comment: Perdon, tienes razon, me confundi con el numero de version, lo que hice fue desinstalar tensorflow y volverlo a instalar, despues instale keras en la version 2.3.1 e instalar wrapt, six y pillow, con eso funciono gracias